# Why do people use i = i + 1 instead of i++?

Tags: javascript, operators

I've seen that in a number of loops and increments. Instead of doing i++ they do i += 1. Why is this?

Comment: Why is your question in the title different from the question in the body? Which one do you mean to ask?

Comment: I use `i += 1`, except in the 3rd-position of a for-loop in which case I use `i++`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not all languages have `++` operator (python, for one)... Probably these people come from a background in one of those languages.  Also some people feel that `i++` is not very clear, especially since some languages treat `i++` and `++i` differently.

Comment: Every language that I know of treats `i++` and `++i` differently in exactly one way: the value of the expression. In other words, `x = i++;` assigns a value less by one to `x` than does `x = ++i`. Is that what you had in mind? I'm curious about your use of the word "some"; do you know of languages that have both prefix and postfix increment operators and don't make this distinction?

Comment: @Ted Hopp Perl will return either a *value* or a *reference* depending on a pre or post increment. This can lead to puzzling behavior. In the basic form this is not an issue. This is very puzzling in cases of `foo($x, ++$x)`, however (evaluation still happens left-to-right). Also, C/C++ has alot of UB with variable modifications (++/--) and access between two sequence points.

Comment: In javascript for browser IE10 (and probably <10 as well) i++ is 15% *slower* than i+=1. Thus I always prefer to use i+=1, just because it's quicker and semantically it is practically the same right.

Answer (score 15):

Personal preference and style.

Answer (score 4):

The general reason is that there are two different versions of increment that behave differently

```
var i = 0;
1 == ++i // true
```

and

```
var i = 0;
1 == i++; // false
```

`++i` translates to "*increment i, then evaluate*" while `i++` translates to "*evaluate i, then increment*"

When you write these expressions as `i = i + 1;` it's clear what the intent of the programmer was and easier to find bugs in the code. It's the same reason people write "*yoda clauses*" like

```
if(6 == x){
    //. . .
}
```

because if you accidentally do

```
if(6 = x){
    //. . .
}
```

it's easier to catch the mistake

Answer (score 3):

Prevents excess craftiness. At least that is what Crockford says.

Comment: However, crafty code will be crafty without "++" and clean code will be clean code with "++".

Answer (score 2):

`i = i + 1` is easier to decode in English.  `i++` although totally correct doesn't translate well when beginners are reading the code.  The programmer was possibly trying to make their code more readable by beginners, or perhaps just not trying to be overly concerned about syntax.  There's no *good* reason to use one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

Some people find `i = i + 1` or `i += 1` more descriptive than `i++`. It's just a matter of coding style and readability. In most current languages there is no performance difference at all between the different ways.

There are some readability issues with the `++` and `--` operators, but that's mostly when they are used along with other operators, it's not really a problem when they are used by themselves. An expression like `++x+-++y+-z++` for example is perfectly valid, but it's hard to see what it actually does. As the operators cause readability issues in some cases, some feel that they should always be avoided.

Comment: This is an extreme, however. While I prefer `+=` to `++`, good code is good code and bad code is bad code: `++x+-++y+-z++` is not good code, `++` aside. For instance, imagine if the "rule" for using `i++` (or even `++i`) is "only in a statement context". This no different than the "rules" that restrict the use of `x=i=i+1` or other such monstrosities.

Comment: @pst: Of course it's bad code, the point with the example was to demonstrate that the operators can be used to write unreadable code.