# Slide to next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="inline-wrapper">
  <div class="inline-blocks" id="f">123</div>
  <div class="inline-blocks" id="s">123</div>
  <div class="inline-blocks" id="t">123</div>
  <div class="inline-blocks" id="fo">123</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
/*  overflow: hidden;*/
}

.inline-wrapper{
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.inline-blocks{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

>.inline-blocks:nth-child(1){
  background-color: #000;
}

.inline-blocks:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
}

.inline-blocks:nth-child(3){
  background-color: red;
}

.inline-blocks:nth-child(4){
  background-color: green;
}
```

How can I slide them without ID?
In fact this is the work of the slider. But I can not understand the logic.
Want to understand how flipping without ID.
We must check the blocks and give them сurrent class.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question... where do you want to slide them to? You mean you want them to scroll left and right? Also, what do you mean by "flipping without ID"? Do you want to create a flipping animation of each `.inline-blocks`?

Comment: you can use the `jQuery Cycle` plugin to flip the elements http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Where is ur jQuery code?

Comment: @janaspage , slide means image 1 shuould goto left / Invisible ,then thru animation , image 2 comes from right and becomes visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto Slide

HTML:

```
<div class="inline-wrapper">
    <div class="inline-blocks" id="f">123</div>
    <div class="inline-blocks" id="s">123</div>
    <div class="inline-blocks" id="t">123</div>
    <div class="inline-blocks" id="fo">123</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function () {
    var numDivs = $('.inline-wrapper').children().length; //Count children ELements
    var counter = 1;

    function slide(time, counter) {
        var $currentDiv = $('.inline-wrapper .inline-blocks:nth-child(' + counter + ')'); //get next element
        var position = $currentDiv.position(); //get position of next element

        if (numDivs > 1) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollLeft: position.left
            }, time / 2); //Animate to next element
        }
    };

    $('.inline-blocks').on('click', function () {
        counter = counter + 1;
        slide(2000, counter);
    });
})();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TA72K/2/)

Comment: Thanx. become more understandable.
But should not we write so - +counter +1 +?

And I'm trying to implement a click function.
Why with overflow hidden it didn't work?

Comment: `i++` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313710/why-do-people-use-i-i-1-instead-of-i

Comment: Overflow hidden: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301841/how-to-scroll-within-an-overflow-hidden-div-to-a-certain-currently-invisible-ele

Comment: Thank you @Alex, can you show how it's works with click?

Comment: We can:
<div class="block" onClick="slide(2000);">...</div>
$(".block").click(function() {slide(2000);});

But how can we do like this - $(".block").click(function(){});

Comment: Thnx once more.
And with overflow I don't understand.